# Android FTP apache commons not changing directory

Tags: java, android, apache, ftp

I'm trying to change the working directory when transferring a bitmap. The problem is, it isn't changing the directory. It keeps uploading the file to the root folder. Does anyone see any problems in my code? Not sure why it isn't working!

```
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

        try {
            client.connect("myhost");

            boolean login = client.login("un", "pw");

            if (login) {
                Log.d("Test", "Login success...");

                String newDir = "/img/Places/Uploads";

                // Changing working directory
                boolean change = client.changeWorkingDirectory(newDir);
                if (change == true) {
                    Log.d("Working directory is changed.Your New working directory:"
                            , newDir);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Unable to change");
                }
                client.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                String data = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2014-05-29-14-57-17.png";

                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
                boolean result = client.storeFile("/example2.png", in);
                in.close();
                if (result)
                    Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
                //
                // When logout success the logout method returns true.
                //
                boolean logout = client.logout();
                if (logout) {
                    Log.d("Test", "Logout from server...");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("Test", "Login fail...");
            }

            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                //
                // Closes the connection to the FTP server
                //
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note you have both a local and a remote working directory.

Comment: am I changing remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer...seems as though I was changing my local working directory, not remote. I had to change

`boolean result = client.storeFile("/example2.png", in);`

to

`boolean result = client.storeFile("/img/Places/Uploads/example2.png", in);`